# Is there a way to respond to declines on flags?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I just received the following decline comment on a flag I placed:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

The flag was placed on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233101/css-ive-got-a-nested-floating-div-how-do-i-get-it-to-fill-the-entire-100/8233359#8233359).

I'm not worried about the flag weight, but I would be interested in a way to respond to that flag to clarify that I was *not* indicating technical inaccuracies or wrong answer, but rather, exactly what the flag says it's for:

> **not an answer**: This was posted as an answer, but it does not answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Incidentally, a commenter on that answer agrees with my assessment. I may actually be wrong, but if I am, it would be *even more helpful* if I could have that conversation.

Comment: So, you want a channel/method for mods to deal with responses to declined flags *on top of* handling the hundreds of flags that are in the queue. That doesn't seem right. An experienced debater can end up taking up more time than the mod would want. Reflag under the "other" option since you are not worried about flag weight.

Comment: @phwd Yes, I don't want to have or encourage a debate either, but, I don't want to abuse the system by "reflagging" either.  If that's not abusive itself, I'll do that.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that answer. It's not complete - but it admits that it may only be part of the whole. However, it addresses the question with a possible or partial solution. I don't see a reason to make it a comment.

Comment: I'm on the fence on that answer. You might be right and the extra `</div>` might have just been omitted by the OP, but it also looks like a reasonable (if incomplete) answer to the question as stated. Flagging tip: Give moderators as much pertinent information as you can (but please do so concisely). The "not an answer" flag works great for those "Thanks!" and "me too" posts that we can tell at a glance aren't an answer to *any* question. For cases like this where the post looks borderline, we definitely need a little bit more to go on.

Comment: @AdamDavis: Simply acknowledging issues with your own answer doesn't mean that the issues aren't still issues. While I won't pass judgment on the particular answer, I don't think that saying "it admits that it may only be part of the whole" gets you any points.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Are you saying that an answer isn't an answer if it has any issues?  I don't care if it's wrong, nevermind incomplete - it's still an answer.  I think people are going way overboard regarding whether something is an answer or a comment.  Any statement that is a possible solution to the problem is an answer.  There is no need to demote substandard answers to comments as long as they attempt to help solve the problem.

Comment: @Bill Thanks for the info, that's helpful.  I was always under the impression that I should only use "Other" if it didn't *categorize* into one of the other flags.

Comment: @AdamDavis: Of course not. All I'm saying is that you said " It's not complete - but it admits that it may only be part of the whole.," and I'm saying *"So what if it admits that?"*. The answer may be suitable, it may not be, but admitting to it (or not) does not matter one way or the other in terms of its acceptability.

Comment: @Renesis you could have downvoted that, I just did, I am sure one more vote will make him turn it to a comment, I dislike that mods need to step in because the community refuse to vote

Comment: @waffles I did, but somebody gave it a (I think sympathy) upvote, which is actually when I flagged.

Comment: I declined that flag. It's not a great answer but it is an answer all the same. It would be unfair for me to delete or convert to a comment until such time the OP had actually clarified that the missing `</div>` was just a slip up when posting his/her HTML. Even then if it was a wrong answer who am I to judge the technical accuracy of posts. That's to be decided by the community by voting on answers. By flagging this you're asking mods to act as proxies to clear out all the wrong or less than stellar answers using our binding votes which is not what we're here to do.

Comment: @waffles How frustrating, it now has 3(!) upvotes. Those voters must not have read the question (or must not understand HTML).

Comment: @Kev Isn't that what the "not an answer" flag is nearly *always* asking mods to do?  That answer is much more of a comment than many comments I see posted (especially given that definition that comments are for "seeking clarification")

Comment: @Renesis: Looks like an answer to me.  Mods aren't supposed to be judging the technical merits of questions.  If it is kindasorta an answer, we should let the community handle it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no channel for communication about flags other than meta - which you are currently, and correctly, utilizing for that purpose.

If a mod is getting something wrong, then having an open discussion here is a good option.  Although, more often than not you'll probably find that they are correct - and knowing the reason why will help you flag better in the future without consuming more of the moderator's time.